# how to show progress bar, till a list is loaded in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I am developing a windows phone App.I want to display progress bar until a list is loaded completely with all the items.How can I do that??

Comment: Although i'm not entirely sure of how I would go about adding a progress bar, have you considered adding a subtle animation such as a spinner or "Loading." -> "Loading.." -> "Loading..." etc http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/design/hh202917(v=vs.105).aspx has some information on progress bars and alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Loaded event of the ListBoxItem. In loaded event check if the item loaded is the last item in your list.
For example, loading 1 to 10 digits in list.

```
private void ListBoxItem_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBoxItem item = sender as ListBoxItem;
    if(item.Content=="10")
    // entire listbox loaded. Stop Progress bar
    // Use SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.IsVisible to show/hide progess bar on system tray
}
```

Note: In silverlight first ListBox's loaded event is fired and then loaded events for listboxitems in order are fired.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Is there any other way?

Comment: Can you elaborate as to what type of data your listbox shows, because this worked perfectly for me.Is your list databound? Then you need to use obtain datacontext of listbox item and then check if its the last item in your list.

Comment: actually the data to be loaded in list is dynamic and then how can I know which is the last item?

Comment: Extract the datacontext of the listboxitem and check if it is equal to the last element in the your dynamic list. For e.g. , if your list is of class Fruit the use ((sender as ListBoxItem).DataContext as Fruit) to get Fruit object associated with that listboxitem and then check that with last item in your list.